# where .jsp files put in web project

Tags: file, jsp, include, directory, web-inf

I have an issue where to put view (.jsp) file in the web applications.little bit confuse it may be inside the WEB-INF folder or out side the WEB-INF folder.

Lot of spring projects view(.jsp) files are stored inside the WEB-INF folder by creating sub folders.

I saw lot of sample spring projects it includes .jsp files inside the WEB-INF folder.
So What is the best practice for my question

Amila

Answer (score 2):

If your application is `servlet centric` then you may add .jsp file under WEB-INF and request them via `RequestDispatcher`. If it is not then put .jsp outside the `WEB-INF`.

Comment: Thanx AVD, What do you mean by servlet centric.As my knowledge spring application are servlet centric. What about jsp servlet app?

Comment: @AmilaNandanaKumara - less or more MVC